# Confusion about pointer decrement in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Consider following program: (see live demo [here](http://ideone.com/YOXJI6))

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c[]={'s','h','r','e','y','a','\0'};
    char *ptr=c;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%c",ptr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    char (*s)[7];
    s=&c;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%c",(*s)[i]);
    printf("\n");

    ptr=&c[5];       // ptr points to 6th char of string
    for(int i=5;i>=0;i--)
        printf("%c",ptr[i]);
}
```

The program isn't giving expected outcome. The outcome I got is:

shreya

shreya

a

But If I write the last loop like following it works fine.

```
for(int i=5;i>=0;i--)
     printf("%c",c[i]);
```

What I am understanding wrong here about pointers? Why I got only last char as output when I write `printf("%c",ptr[i]);`in last for loop.

Comment: In your program ptr=&c[5]; is not required

Comment: BTW: instead of `char c[]={'s','h','r','e','y','a','\0'};` you can write `char c[]= "shreya";` which is strictly the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you did the assignment

```
ptr=&c[5];
```

You made `ptr` point to the `fifth` element of the array, i.e. `a`. Now inside the loop you are printing `ptr[i]`.

Lets start with the beginning of the loop and see what it prints.

`*(ptr+5)`, which is way beyond the array `c[]`.

```
{'s','h','r','e','y','a','\0'};
  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^    ^    ^  ^  ^  ^
  0   1   2   3   4   5    6    G  G  G  G   //G -> Garbage
                      ^                  ^
                     ptr              (ptr+5)
```

similary, this continues, until `i` is `0`, the last iteration, i.e. `*(ptr+0)` . On which it prints `a`

Comment: you're counting 0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4... where's 2?

Answer (score 5):

Assigning `ptr=&c[5];`you make that `ptr` holds the address of the 5th element of the string.

If you want access preceding elements you need a **negative index** to step-back in the string.

```
ptr=&c[5];       // ptr points to 6th char of string
for(int i=4;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%c",ptr[-i]);
```

Or

```
ptr=&c[5];       // ptr points to 6th char of string
for(int i=-4;i<=0;i++)
    printf("%c",ptr[i]);
```

Please consider also that the 5th element is displaced of 4 positions (because the first is at offset 0, counting from 0 to 4 there are 5 symbols).

The other works because the array `c` always points to the address of element 0.

Answer (score 3):

With `ptr=&c[5];` your pointer is pointing to 'a'

First loop will point to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of will be address of `'a'+5` and so on.

What you need is:

```
ptr=&c[5];
for(int i=5;i>=0;i--){
    printf("%c",*ptr);
    ptr--;
}
```

Or

```
ptr=c;
for(int i=5;i>=0;i--){
    printf("%c",ptr[i]);
}
```

Many other ways to do that..

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this part of the code:

```
ptr=&c[5];       // ptr points to 6th char of string
for(int i=5;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%c",ptr[i],i);
```

Change the above to:

```
ptr=&c[5];       // ptr points to 6th char of string
for(int i=5;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%c",ptr[i-5],i);
```

`ptr[i]` can you take you an undefined reference since `ptr+5`, `ptr+4`, etc may not be accessible and they do not point to the array.

A better way would have been simply to point at the base of the array and print like this:

```
ptr=&c[0];       // ptr points to the base address of the char array
for(int i=5;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%c",ptr[i]);
```